# Question potentially off-topic, judment and possible migration needed

Tags: discussion, migration

In regards to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/980528/snort-is-receiving-traffic-but-doesnt-appear-to-be-applying-rules). I *am* an IT Professional and I *am* doing sysadmin work on a network appliance and server on what is my primary business network. However, I do not use it to provide services to clients.

None the less, I'm beginning to think the reason I'm getting neither downvotes or answers is that the question rides the line between on-topic and off-topic. I wanted to request a judgement on whether it should be migrated to another site, which site, and (if needed) request a moderator to do so.

So, should the linked question be moved? If so, to where? Unix/Linux?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I read through the question but I don't see anything that would make it obviously off topic, nor did I see anything that suggested any other site in the network would be a better place to ask.

You originally posted it on the weekend, when we have fewer people overall reading the site. It looks like you edited it today, which does bring it back to the homepage.

But there just aren't a lot of people following questions about [snort](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/snort) so it may take a while before someone who can answer it sees it.

In such circumstances the [usual advice](https://serverfault.com/help/no-one-answers) is to continue to add details to the question and offer a bounty. You don't have much reputation yet, so I've put a 500 reputation bounty on the question. Do your part by continuing to add any possibly relevant details to the question. (BTW, you shouldn't add things like "UPDATE:" to the question. The edit history is visible to everyone.)

Comment: whoa, thanx. And noted regarding "update".